# InjectionUtils - Parameter Class has no constructor

Tags: data-binding, cxf, jax-rs

I am trying to send a post request with cxf implementation. But I am getting `InjectionUtils - Parameter Class SizeQuantityBean has no constructor with single String parameter, static valueOf(String) or fromString(String) methods` error while binding a class.
My code to send request:

```
sellerService.register(sellerBean);
```

Implementation:

```
@Path(BASE_PATH + "/register")
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
BaseBean register(@QueryParam("") SellerBean sellerBean){
   ...
   ... 
}
```

`SellerBean` class has List of `SizeQuantityBean`. How to reslove this conflict?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried removing `@QueryParam` annotation because your request is POST, you should use no tag body.

Comment: I did the exact same mistake with PUT and looked for this stupid copy and paste problem forever. Thanks!